# Firebase storage error 1200 over wifi only, LTE works perfectly

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

This error started to pop this week. It is really weird. Code is just a simple putdata on Firebase Storage to save an image. (Swift 5 // XCode 11.3.1)

```
    storageRef.putData(profileImageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            completion?(nil)
            return
        }

        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                completion?(nil)
                return
            }

            completion?(url?.absoluteString)
        })


    })
```

Then what I get back over LTE is: Success. 
What I get back over my home Wifi is:

> 2020-02-16 13:44:49.944697-0800 persona[17889:5050090] Task <0E3D8C0D-6B4C-43CF-B897-E549E8D5301E>.<2> finished with error [-1200] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Updates: Worked when tried on another Wifi. No configuration change was made on the original wifi.

Comment: Please pay attention to tags and product names. Firestore is a product in the Firebase platform. But you're asking about the Cloud Storage for Firebase product, which is completely different. Using the right tags makes it more likely somebody will see your question who can actually help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Great. Any ideas on what's going on? By the way, it was called Storage under Firebase before. Not "cloud-storage". So it's not quite off the ballpark the tags. But thx for adjusting it.

Comment: Turned the wi-fi router off. Seemed to have solved it. Worked for a while. Got back to being stuck. Only the Storage communication is off. Firestore is responding normally read/write.

Comment: It sounds like you may have resolved this issue but what is the use case from putting code that runs on a background thread into a dispatch queue? That just looks odd to me.

Comment: Nah... that was just a weird copy/paste, shouldn't be there. Will edit. The issue is not solved though. Google still working on it. Follow the thread below.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that move the needle.

1) For reading from Firebase Storage: I've changed my URLSession.shared.dataTask to use KingFisher instead, this solved for reading.

2) Switching Wifi's seems to solve it too, but I hardly believe this is a sustainable answer.

Issue is caused by xFinity Comcast Advanced Security filter, Firebase team is working on it. Follow the thread on Firebase's Github here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4913

Comment: We've had users report similar issues - firestore works ok, but firebase storage reads dont. Seems to be localised to US and to specific wifi providers - Xfinity by comcast.

Comment: Interesting. In my case it just magically started to work again. In my opinion someone at Comcast did something wrong trying to improve their filters or something.

Comment: out of curiosity, were you on a comcast/xfinity wifi as well?

Comment: Yes. And the issue is back on today.